# react-native onPress binding with an argument

Tags: binding, react-native

The desired behaviour is to pass an argument (text) to the onClick handler to console.log it but it seems that I'm doing something wrong with the syntax.

If I leave the argument out as below, it's working fine:

```
export default class Nav extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.pickNumber(3);
  }

  onPress() {
    console.log('FOOOBAAR');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>####################</Text>
        <Text>Intro Screen</Text>
        <Text>Number: {this.props.numbers}</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}>
          <Text>Go to Foo</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

However, if I want to pass an argument to the onPress handler, it complains 'Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined.

```
export default class Nav extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.pickNumber(3);
  }

  onPress(txt) {
    console.log(txt);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>####################</Text>
        <Text>Intro Screen</Text>
        <Text>Number: {this.props.numbers}</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPress('foo').bind(this)}>
          <Text>Go to Foo</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

Thanks

Addition: 
If I change it to:

```
onPress={this.onPress.bind('foo')}
```

it does not work either.

Comment: As an aside, technically, `bind` is not necessary at all in this case since `this` is not referenced in the `onPress` function.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can do the binding in the constructor by using ES6:

```
export default class Nav extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this);
  }
```

and then

```
  onPress(txt) {
    console.log(txt);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>####################</Text>
        <Text>Intro Screen</Text>
        <Text>Number: {this.props.numbers}</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onPress('foo')}>
          <Text>Go to Foo</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It removes the error but the 'foo' string gets console.logged automatically without me even clicking.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my answer. You need to add () => before this.onPress('foo').

Comment: That's it. Thanks. Would you be able to explain why I needed to add a fat arrow function to that? Thank you

Comment: Without the fat arrow function, we are executing a function instead of giving onPress a function so we need the arrow function to create a function for onPress.

Comment: no need to bind the function when you use `onPress={() => }` because it is done automaticaly

Comment: @inga Love U! s2

Comment: Does anybody know why the fat arrow is needed? I mean, it's onPress, why would we want to put a function in there that loads without being pressed? It's not onLoadDoThis, it's onPressDoThis.

Comment: The reason you use the fat arrow is as follows: `this.onPress.bind(this)` returns the bound function and this is passed to the `onPress` prop. However, `this.onPress('foo')` without the fat arrow will call the function `onPress` immediately with the parameter `foo`. Since this function doesn't explicitly return anything, `undefined` gets returned and this is what is passed to the `onPress` prop. However, the `onPress` property is expecting a function to execute only after the user clicks. `() =>` creates (and returns) a function using ES6 syntax.

Answer (score 36):

You can avoid binding the function in the constructor by binding it at the onPress value and passing the argument after 'this'. You can refactor your code like so,

```
export default class Nav extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.pickNumber(3);
  }

  onPress(txt) {
    console.log(txt);  // foo
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>####################</Text>
        <Text>Intro Screen</Text>
        <Text>Number: {this.props.numbers}</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPress.bind(this,'foo')}>
          <Text>Go to Foo</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

The first argument is 'this' and any other arguments can be supplied after that which will be received in the same order.

Update : Can do this using closures too.

```
export default class Nav extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.pickNumber(3);
  }

  onPress = (this, txt) => () => {
    console.log(txt);  // foo
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>####################</Text>
        <Text>Intro Screen</Text>
        <Text>Number: {this.props.numbers}</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPress(this,'foo')}>
          <Text>Go to Foo</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Very handy indeed since the fat arrow functions will ppbly trigger re-renders as react cannot cache this

Comment: eslint doesn't really like this: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md

Comment: This should be the preferred answer, as it avoids creating a new anonymous function each press as the most highly rated answer will do...

Comment: Not true, `this.onPress.bind(this, 'foo')` [still leads to re-render](https://medium.com/@adamjacobb/react-native-performance-arrow-functions-binding-3f09cbd57545). So this method has the same effect as the fat arrow function.

Comment: @FanchenBao so, how did you fix it?

Comment: @DroidLearner I use the simplest method `onPress={() => someCallBack('foo')}`, the same one as described in the accepted answer. Regarding the rerendering issue with the fat arrow function, I did **NOT** observe any rerendering in my testing when it is used as onPress callback. So I don't have any issue using fat arrow function. Also note that this answer has been edited after my previous response. The edit fixed the problem I raised and it looks fine to me now.

Answer (score 25):

You can solve it with fat arrows too:

```
export default class Nav extends Component {

  handlePress = (text) => {
    console.log(text);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>####################</Text>
        <Text>Intro Screen</Text>
        <Text>Number: {this.props.numbers}</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.handlePress('weeeeee')}>
          <Text>Go to Foo</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This method works, but it's less efficient. Whenever you tap that variable, the function needs to be created, and then executed. If you use the function definition, and then the bind, whenever you tap, the function only gets called and it isn't created every time.

Answer (score 12):

You should just pass one fat arrow function before calling the function.

```
onPress= {()=> this.handlePress(param)}
```

Comment: This is far and away the most simple and straight forward answer thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Define function and call it onPress of Text. If you are iterating over array then you can also pass title

```
  selectText = (item) => {
            console.log(item) // will print Text Pressed
            alert(item)
      }
   return(
       <View>
       <Text onPress = {()=>this.selectText("Text Pressed")}>Press for Alert</Text>
       </View>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
const onChangeHandler = index => { console.log(index) }
onPress={onChangeHandler.bind(this, index)}
```