# How to bind a value for TouchableOpacity

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native and trying to develop an app which can navigate between different screens. For that I am using Navigate. But the problem is when multiple TouchableOpacity components are being pushed through an array and then returned to my view using a function, the navigator is fetching parameter value for last variable value of the loop.

```
// my function to push dynamic blocks in render function
    myFunction() {
      var myelement = [];
      for ( var i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++ )
      {
// loop goes twice pushing 2 TouchableOpacity blocks setting dynamic i values
        myelement.push(
          <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={1}
            onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2', {
              mykey: `value${i}`,
            })>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      }
      return myelement;
    }
```

When the 1st TouchableOpacitiy block is clicked (as the loop only goes twice creating only 2 blocks) the value of i should be 0.

But instead the it is taking the final value of i = 1

Comment: from what I have found and tried, the closest I could come was to binding but unable to bind the value to this.props.navigation.navigate()

Comment: `onPress` expects a function - try changing it to `() => this.props.navigation...`

Comment: Thanks, just tried but still the same issue

Comment: finally found the logic in this post answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45371547/11391535

Comment: Yes, @GauravMittal that's the one

Answer (score 0):

I think this could solve your problem:

```
myFunction() {
  const myElement = [];

  const newElement = [0,1].map(el => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      activeOpacity={1}
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2', {
          mykey: `value${el}`,
      })>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ));
  return myElement.push(newElement);
}
```