# React Native: Accessing style values using refs

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

If I have the following render:

```js
 render() {
    return (
      <View ref={this.bgRef} style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: "black"}]}> //want to access backgroundColor property
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={this.onPress}
        ><Text>Click Me</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

How would I access the **backgroundColor** style of **this.bgRef** in an "onPress" callback?

For example, if I wanted the background color to swap between black and white every time the button is pressed, how would I access the current color? I am aware that states could be used to solve this issue, but am wondering if there is a way to do it using refs. Is there a similar method to **ref.current.setNativeProps** that instead returns the value of specific properties?

***EDIT:***

I've edited my question to include the entirety of my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.bgRef = React.createRef()
    this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this);
  }
  onPress() {
    if (this.bgRef.current.style.backgroundColor == "black") {
      this.bgRef.current.style.backgroundColor = "white"
    } else {
      this.bgRef.current.style.backgroundColor = "black"
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View ref={this.bgRef} style = {[styles.container, {backgroundColor: "black"}]}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => this.onPress()}
        ><Text style={styles.paragraph}>Click Me</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#DDDDDD",
    padding: 10
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can change styles using ref

```
this.bgRef.current.style.backgroundColor = 'salmon';
this.bgRef.current.style.color = 'red';
```

Comment: I tested this and it worked when I used "web view" on my expo snack, but when I switched it to IOS it returned:

"undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.bgRef.current.style.backgroundColor')"

Comment: Please try and bind your onPress function.

Comment: So sorry... I am a beginner and am unsure what binding a function is. I referred to the following question when attempting it myself [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017807/react-native-onpress-binding-with-an-argument). Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error. Could you please provide an example of how I would bind a function?

Comment: I've also edited my question to display the code where I attempt to bind the onPress function.

Comment: I logged out `this.bgRef.current` and turns out there is no style property, that is why you get this error. Using `setNativeProps` or `state` might be the only solutions available for now.

Comment: I see… weird that it worked on web view and not IOS. Thank you so much!